# Smooth functionals in the contragredient representation of a locally profinite group

Tags: representation-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, automorphic-forms

I'm reading Bump's book *Automorphic Forms and Representations* and getting stuck in Section 4.2 about contragredient representation of smooth representations.

Setup: Let $G$ be a locally profinite group (i.e. totally disconneted, Hausdorff and locally compact, e.g. $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{Q}_p)$) and $K$ be its compact open subgroup. Let $(\pi, V)$ be a smooth representation of $G$. Then by Bump's Proposition 4.2.2, we see
$$
V = \oplus_{\rho \in \widehat{K}} V(\rho),
$$
where $\widehat{K}$ is the set of equivalent classes of irreducible smooth representations of $K$ (which are automatically of finite dimension with open kernel) and $V(\rho)$ is the $\rho$-isotypic part of $V$. Then
$$
V^{\ast} = \prod_{\rho \in \widehat{K}} (V(\rho))^{\ast}, \quad (\star)
$$
where $(-)^{\ast}$ is the *linear* dual of $-$.

**Problem for me**: Then to isolate the smooth linear functionals in $V^{\ast}$, Bump claimed that **it is not difficult to see that a linear functional $\lambda \in V^{\ast}$ is smooth if and only if $\lambda$ is zero on all but finitely many of the summands in $(\star)$**.

**My question**: **How to show this claim?**

**My attempts**: I have managed to show the $(\Leftarrow)$ direction. Indeed, note that a linear functional $\lambda$ is smooth if and only if there exist an open subgroup $H$ of $G$ such that $\lambda = \lambda \circ \pi(h)$ for any $h \in H$. Now for $\lambda$ vanishing on all but finitely many summands $\rho_1, \ldots, \rho_k$, taking $H := \cap_{i=1}^{k} \ker \rho_i$ does the trick.

**BUT, how to show the $(\Rightarrow)$ direction?**

Thank you all for answering or commenting! :)